# Polymer Dart event bubbling

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm firing an event from an internal element with the `canBubble` flag to `false` but the event is caught by an external element.

Here the relevant HTML code:

```dart
<link rel="import" href="../../packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<script type="application/dart" src="main_app.dart"></script>

<polymer-element name="external-element">
  <template>
    <internal-element></internal-element>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name="internal-element">
  <template>
    <button on-click={{onButtonClick}}>Click</button>
  </template>
</polymer-element>
```

And the relative Dart code:

```dart
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';

@CustomTag('external-element')
class ExternalElement extends PolymerElement {

  ExternalElement.created() : super.created() {
    addEventListener("my-event", (e){
      print("$this event $e");
    });
  }
}

@CustomTag('internal-element')
class InternalElement extends PolymerElement {

  InternalElement.created() : super.created() {
    addEventListener("my-event", (e){
      print("$this event $e");
    });
  }

  void onButtonClick() {
    print('onButtonClick');

    fire("my-event", canBubble: false, cancelable:false);
  }
}
```

Why the event is bubbling to the external element?

Note: I've tried with Dart and simple HTML and the event propagation works fine.

Comment: Can you check in the event handler if the `bubbles` attribute is set in the received event? (not sure if the attribute name `bubbles` is correct but I guess you'll figure it out). I guess there is a bug somewhere so the value isn't properly set in the resulting event.

Comment: The `bubbles` attribute is `false`.

Comment: Did you also try in Chrome/Firefox (JavaScript)? It could be a shadow DOM polyfill issue or a generic Dart event issue. Trying to create a non-bubbling event in a non-Polymer Dart project using `element.dispatchEvent()` would probably show where the issue comes from.

Comment: Just got the update. You mean when canBubble is set to false is does not bubble in pure Dart and simple HTML? Then I assume it is a Polymer polyfill (shadow DOM) issue. What you could check if it behaves the same if you use `element.dispatchEvent()` in Polymer. Could be an issue with the `fire()` helper method.

Comment: Yes, it works has expected: the event firer (the internal element) gets the event but not the external element.

Comment: Same happens in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: I just skimmed a bit through but this might have some relevant info https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/296

Comment: I've tried also with Polymer but I get a weird behavior: the firer element is not notified if the canBubble is set to false and also the external, as expected, is not notified. 
http://jsfiddle.net/Fedy2/hg4kn9Lf/2/

I think I should open an issue in both Polymer and Polymer Dart.